# How can I transfer value from selectbox to textbox?

Tags: javascript, textbox, onchange

I'm using a database and there are 3 columns such as id, bname, and author.
Selectbox takes its value from database's bname column. I can send bname value to textbox by using "onchange="this.form.author.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value". But I want to call author value into textbox by taking from database when selectbox changed. How can I do this?

```
<td>Book name :<select name="bname">
<% do while not a.eof %> 
<option value="<%=a("bname")%>"><%=a("bname")%></option>
<% a.movenext
loop%></select></td>
<td>Author: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="author"></font></td>
```

Comment: No buddy, I want to make write it in the textbox in order to post to another form.

Comment: I'm sorry. dsayi would be author.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to append the author's name to your textbox.  You can use your same code with one little change, add the +=:

```
<select name="bname" onchange="this.form.dsayi.value+=this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML">
```

Comment: Thank you phpmeh. But it doesn't work. It must send "author" value to textbox. This code sends "bname" value to textbox.

Comment: double checked myself.. it was innerHTML not text.

Comment: Probably I couldn't tell my problem. I tried, it works but it calls wrong value. It writes bookname but it must write author name by taking author's name from database when selectbox changed.